# tar.bz2 cannot stat: no such file or directory

Tags: tar, bz2

I am compressing 60G of a backup of a bank using the command below, but the log informs the following messages. 
What can it be?

Command:

```
BZIP=-9 tar -cvjf /backup/backup-mysql-'date "+%Y%m%d"'.tar.bz2 /backup/backup-mysql
```

Error:

```
tar: "+%Y%m%d".tar.bz2: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following command:

```
tar -cvjf /backup/backup-mysql-$(date "+%Y%m%d").tar.bz2 /backup/backup-mysql
```